# MVP and EventBus : who is appropriate for listening events - view or presenter?

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, mvp, greenrobot-eventbus

I am using Model-View-Presenter design pattern with eventbus. I have a presenter that posts an event in eventbus whenever some information is updated like this:

```
public class HomeScreenPresenter extends BaseHomePresenter {
 ...
 ...

    locationUpdatesManager.getCurrentPlace(place -> {
             EventBus.getDefault().post(new OnCurrentPlaceDetailsUpdated(place));
       }
    );
}
```

now, I want that place details in some other fragment. So all I have done is inside that fragment like this:

```
public class PlaceListFragment extends BaseListFragment implements PlaceListView {

    protected EventBus eventBus;

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        initComponents();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        eventBus.register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        eventBus.unregister(this);
        super.onStop();
    }

    @CallSuper
    @Override
    protected void initComponents() {
        eventBus = EventBus.getDefault();
    }


    @DebugLog
    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void onCurrentPlaceUpdatedEvent(OnCurrentPlaceDetailsUpdated onCurrentPlaceUpdated) {
          //got the event
 }
}
```

Is it good or bad in terms of decoupling and design? **Should I subscribe the events in presenter for `PlaceListFragment` and then callback to fragment using `PlaceListView`?**

Comment: I tend to bind presenter to event bus when the view is bound to it, and unbind from event bus when the view unbinds itself.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce thanks...but another problem is that I don't want to listen for events when user goes into background. In the presenter way, I will have some kind of lifecycle to handle when fragment's onStart and onStop is being called. Is it good to have presenters with lifecycles? or any other solution to this?

Comment: I froze my bus and resumed it in `onPause()` and `onPostResume()` respectively.